# Clicking a SVG element in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, svg, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

Im trying to click a specific state in this svg map.
https://petdiseasealerts.org/forecast-map#/

But even when i give the correct xpath, it still says

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: (//*[local-name()='svg'])[5]/*[@id='features']/*[@id='regions']/*[@id='alabama'] (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
```

What will be the solution for this

This is my code.

```
package org.example;

import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import java.time.Duration;


/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App 
{

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws InterruptedException {

        String state ="alabama";

        String stateElement = "(//*[local-name()='svg'])[5]/*[@id='features']/*[@id='regions']/*[@id='"+state+"']";


        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.http.factory", "jdk-http-client");
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
        driver.get("https://petdiseasealerts.org/forecast-map#/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(stateElement))).click();

        driver.quit();

        System.out.println( "End" );
    }
}
```

Comment: Only HTML elements have a click method.